# Add Secondary Text to Responsive Image

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I'm fairly new to coding. I would appreciate any help I can get on this.

Is there a way to add secondary text above the background image right under the main header that is also responsive?

I'd like the ability to style the text differently than the h2 header.

I've tried a few different ways of doing this, but none of them worked out. :-( The new text would just overlap in mobile mode instead of stacking under the header.

Appreciate the help if someone could take a look at this code to see what I'm missing.

```css
.homepagetext:after {
content:"";
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 8%,rgba(50,50,50,0.1) 56%,rgba(161,161,161,0) 66%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* old IE fallback */
  width: 200%;
  height: 400%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}


body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-image: url(https://globalonline.blob.core.windows.net/globalonlinecourses/Bannerz_1205.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/SRU39R3XRV.jpg */
  background-size: cover; /* version standardisée */
}


h2 {
  font-family: 'karbon';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 35%;
  top: 15%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 0px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2 class="homepagetext">Introduction to <BR><em>GEORGRAPHIC INFORMATION SYSTEMS</em></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a few things are throwing you off the trail.

Position absolute is great for putting text over images, but because your image is a background, you don't need it to style to get text to appear over the background image.

**Remove:**

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

```css
.homepagetext:after {
content:"";
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 8%,rgba(50,50,50,0.1) 56%,rgba(161,161,161,0) 66%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* old IE fallback */
  width: 200%;
  height: 400%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}


body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-image: url(https://globalonline.blob.core.windows.net/globalonlinecourses/Bannerz_1205.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/SRU39R3XRV.jpg */
  background-size: cover; /* version standardisée */
}


h2 {
  font-family: 'karbon';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px 25px 0 25px;
  margin:0;
  position: static;
  border: 0px solid white;
}
.new-class{
  color:#bada55;
  padding:0 25px;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2 class="homepagetext">Introduction to <BR><em>GEORGRAPHIC INFORMATION SYSTEMS</em></h2>
  <p class="new-class">secondary text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Matt! :-) This was incredibly helpful!